# Unity UI Text Turning Black

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an extremely annoying problem with Unity (2019.1.3f1) and mac os, where UI text color randomly turns black in editor (and happens when in play mode too) and seems to only get fixed when i save the scene(but only temporarily). These are all standard UI Text (part of an asset actually, is the whole menu system I am using).

I have been seeing other people mentioning it online few years back even, but no definitive solution. Is anyone else having that ? Is there any solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Had the same issue also in `2019.1.3` Color in the `Text` component was still white but in SceneView and GameView it appeared black. However after building everything is fine .. might be (or actually pretty sure is) a bug. Do you maybe happen to be on OpenGL?

Answer (score 9):

quick fix for black UI text is to disable and then enable canvas into editor
then ctlr+s (save)

takes 2 seconds to do

also not a real fix as the text will get back to black on next build

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a bug within the Unity editor itself, and introduced somehwere in 2019.1.0f2. As far as I am aware cannot be completely fixed by yourself. The only things that seem to temporarily "fix" this issue are doing one of the following things:

- Save the scene (as you've found)
- Restart the editor
- Build the project
- At occasion starting the scene *sometimes* fixes it, but really unreliable.

Although not exactly the same problem, [bug 1143135](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/image-color-cannot-be-changed-via-script-when-image-type-is-set-to-simple) is most likely related to the issue. According to the current state of issue 1143135 that will be fixed in version 2019.1.5f1 and 2019.2.0b4.

For the time being it seems we can only hope that that issue is indeed related. And if not put in another bug report.

Comment: ahh, thanks for letting me know. This is such an annoyance, I am very surprised it hasn't been a top bug fix priority.

Comment: @Spyros probably because as said it doesn't affect the build .. it only annoys within the editor ;)

Comment: @derHugo still very annoying though :/ Hope they fix it soon.

Comment: I have seen this issue in both Windows and Mac. In Mac this will be solved if I just minimize and restore the Editor. But in Windows I have to save the scene.

Answer (score 0):

So I was having this problem right now and I'm not sure if it is the same one but I got it to stay the same color when playtesting by going to Edit> Preferences> Colors> Playmode tint: change it to white. It worked for me hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should consider [registering an account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup) to get access to more of Stack Overflow's features.

Answer (score 0):

Go Window in top then rendering - lightning and click generate lightning data.
it fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by simply restarting the unity though.